Increased thickness at the edges after "Bevel"
I'm trying to make a flat outline of constant thickness using "Bevel" for four edges, but I get rougher edges:

I'd like to try any (preferably simple (without curves, etc)) ways to get constant thickness for my outline.
I get the following geometry breaks:




You can do it another way:
Only keep 4 vertices, bevel the vertices:

Activate the addon called Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools, press E > Offset Edges > Extrude:

Set the Width in the Operator Box:


Thanks so much, I tried it. But then I add one middle edge loop, move it along the Z-axis, and bevel this loop. And I get some geometry breaks. I attached two pictures in my starting post.

maybe before the bevel try to select all and M > Merge by Distance?

I've just tried it. It doesn't help (no vertices were removed). There're two problem vertices, that spoil the geometry.

Please share the object (before the bevel)

I attached the BLEND file before the bevel.

you have inverted normals, recalculate the normal (Shift N) @misha.physics

Oh, yes. Thanks! (I had to check it.)
