How to model rounded corners that fit together for a logo animation similar to Prime Video?
i am working on a logo animation similar to Prime Video, where rounded corners move sequentially. However, i am having trouble modeling the corners properly. Every time i try to create one corner i cant seem to make the subsequent corners fit together seamlessly.
How can i model rounded corners that fit perfectly with each other and maintain their shape throughout the animation?



Can you link to a video of said intro? This may depend heavily on how the pieces are animated.

I included already but here is the intro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2YxT-G0rEY

Oh, I see it now. Ok, they just need to move up and down. That seems easy...

Oh, that was really easy. Thanks @TheLabCat! I don't know if anyone else has encountered this problem, but here's what I did:
1-Create a curve and shape it the way you want.
2-Convert the curve to a mesh.
3-Add a solidify modifier to the mesh.
4-Duplicate the object and right-click to confirm.
5-Adjust the offset value in the solidify modifier for each duplicate (I increased it by 2 for each shape).
https://i.imgur.com/1h57nLM.png

That seems to be a complete answer. Please post it as such. (Meanwhile I'm out here trying to make a more flexible solution with Geometry Nodes but my deleted comment was all you needed, lol)

my answer may help here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/325006/increased-thickness-at-the-edges-after-bevel/325008#325008

Add a bezier curve obj, in edit mode, right click > Subdivide, raise its resolution from 12 to 32 or 64, move, rotate and scale as you like, add some extrusion, add a 90 degrees tilt if needed.

In object mode, right click > Convert to Mesh, add some extra edge loops (Ctrl R), add a solidify modifer and a Bevel Modifier.

In face select mode, Alt click to select a loop of faces, then press P > Separate Selection. Repeat for all loops.

Move and animate.


I don't know if anyone else has encountered this problem, but here's what I did:

-Create a curve and shape it the way you want.
-Convert the curve to a mesh.
-Add a solidify modifier to the mesh.
-Duplicate the object and right-click to confirm.
-Adjust the offset value in the solidify modifier for each
duplicate (I increased it by 2 for each shape).



Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF
